# Python convert csv column to specify list type

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I read my csv file column,and I get a str like '[0.123,0.1234,0.12345]'

How to transform this str to a list like [0.123,0.1234,0.12345]

I use pandas to read csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[0.123,0.1234,0.12345]')
[0.123, 0.1234, 0.12345]
```

Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Comment: Thanks. It really help me.